# Computing $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{t^a}{1+t^2}dt$ for $-1<a<0$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am integrating the following integral

> $$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{t^a}{1+t^2}dt$$ for $-1<a<0$.

by computing residues inside some contour. But I'm not sure what contour to use here, since $z^{a}$ gets large when $z$ is small, so I have to be careful about the part of the contour that gets near the origin.

Comment: A keyhole contour. The growth of $\lvert z\rvert^\alpha$ near $0$ is more than compensated by the shrinking of the length of the circle of radius $\rho$.

Comment: What Daniel said.  Because $a>-1$, $z^a$ grows slowly enough that you don't need to worry

Comment: $-1 < \Re\left(a\right) < \color{red}{1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the keyhole contour suggested, with outer radius $R$ and inner radius $\epsilon$.  The contour integral becomes

$$\int_{\epsilon}^R dx \frac{x^a}{1+x^2} + i R \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{R^a e^{i a \theta}}{1+R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}}\\ + e^{i 2 \pi a} \int_R^{\epsilon} dx \frac{x^a}{1+x^2} + i \epsilon \int_{2 \pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{\epsilon^a e^{i a \phi}}{1+\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}}$$

Because $a \in (-1,0)$, the second and fourth integrals vanish as $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$, respectively.

On the other hand, the contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at the poles $z=e^{i \pi/2}$ and $z=e^{i 3 \pi/2}$.  Thus we have

$$\left ( 1-e^{i 2 \pi a}\right ) \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^a}{1+x^2} = \frac{i 2 \pi}{2 i} \left (e^{i \pi a/2} - e^{i 3 \pi a/2} \right )$$

or

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^a}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2 \cos{(\pi a/2)}}$$

Comment: Where does the $e^{i2\pi a}$ before the third integral come from?

Comment: Because on this leg of the contour, $z=x e^{i 2 \pi}$.  Although this seems like a triviality, this is crucial in exploiting the multivaluedness if the integrand.

Comment: Assuming your comment is missing $a$ in the exponent.  If $z=xe^{i2\pi a}$ then... shouldn't $\theta$ in the second and fourth integrals run from $0$ to $2\pi a$, instead of $2\pi$ ?

Comment: @Andomar: No!  The parametrization of the contour is as I stated.  Please work it through carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about multi-valuedness, I am just trying to understand your answer.  My knowledge is incomplete and I cannot picture a keyhole where the circles have 180 degrees but the two lines have different angles.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28IV.29_.E2.80.93_branch_cuts

Comment: Thanks, that clears some things up.  I guess you can integrate until the branch cut because an integrand doesn't have to be defined at the start and end points, it just has to have a limit going near them.